# progress bars for portfolio items

Tags: rally

I'm looking to create a custom roadmap app using Portfolio items.

I think this will be pretty straightforward, but I would very much like to incorporate the % done bars that portfolio items have into my tables.

Since these are not part of the SDK, is it possible to get the javascript that will have the same look and feel as when the % done bars are displayed in the custom grids, along with the warnings etc for stories that don't have estimates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wait on trying to re-implement the percent done bars in your custom app. We are feverishly working on the second edition of our SDK and the percent bar is currently a part of that release.

As a side note recreating the algorithm that colors the cards would be a pain and I would wait for us to complete the new SDK with the component. It is surprising how many edge cases there are in that one little bar.

Comment: Ok-- that's good news.  But can you give a sense of when?  Potentially in a month, within 3 months, within 6 months?  Thanks!!!

Comment: I can tell you we hope to have a beta available soon. I wish I could give you an exact date but things are still in flux.

Comment: I don't need an exact date, but a window of some sort would be very helpful (e.g. less than six months)

Comment: I will be very sad if we do not have something you can use in less than six months. My hope is much sooner than that