# Rally percent done by story count and plan estimate color coding algorithm

Tags: javascript, rally, appsdk2

Related to [Progress Bars for Portfolio Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789001/progress-bars-for-portfolio-items/9794478#9794478), but now we have the SDK 2.0

Is there a way to see the algorithm for displaying percent done by story count and percent done by story plan estimate?

I have an attempt which is close, and works in most cases, but sometimes when I compare it to the actual information in rally, the colors differ.  I would like this to be consistent for my app:

```
if (recordData.PercentDoneByStoryPlanEstimate === 1) {                                                                           //All work has been accepted
    return App.colorCodes.grey;
} else if (dateDifference <= 0) {                                                                                                //End date has passed and work is not complete
    return App.colorCodes.blank;
} else {
    if (daysSinceStart / dateDifference <= recordData.PercentDoneByStoryPlanEstimate)             return App.colorCodes.green;  //On-track
    else if (daysSinceStart / dateDifference <= recordData.PercentDoneByStoryPlanEstimate + 0.25) return App.colorCodes.yellow; //Within 25% of planned velocity
    else                                                                                          return App.colorCodes.red;    //Off-track, not within 10%
}
```

Also, the [Percent Done](https://prod.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.PercentDone) ui component in the SDK 2.0 does not color the cards correctly either, and there is no way to provide a custom coloring function - I can provided a percentage, but can I get it to display like a native rally percent done would?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see how the math is generated for the Percent Done component you can see the [Health Color Calculator](https://prod.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/source/HealthColorCalculator.html#Rally-util-HealthColorCalculator) or look directly at the [source](https://prod.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/source/HealthColorCalculator.html#Rally-util-HealthColorCalculator). These components should show the calculations as they are represented in Rally (since this is the code we use!).

Comment: And what about using this to return the correct colors for a Percent Done ui component?

Comment: Still wondering about the Percent Done UI component - any way to customize the coloring for that?

Comment: If you want to change the colors you can overwrite the CSS that is used. As long as you are ok with how the colors are calculated you can change it to whatever color you are interested in

Comment: Sorry, what I mean by that is - the coloring algorithm.  It only incorporates the percentage your provide in determining a color