# Rally percent done ui component

Tags: javascript, rally, appsdk2

Related to [Rally percent done by story count and plan estimate color coding algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221134/rally-percent-done-by-story-count-and-plan-estimate-color-coding-algorithm), but asking the unanswered portion here.

The [Percent Done ui component](https://prod.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.PercentDone) in the SDK 2.0 does not color the cards according to the algorithm used by rally (it only color codes based on a percentage).  Is there any way to provide a color coding function or a rendering function to change this functionality to line up with Rally's? Thanks!

[EDIT] - attempting to override existing functionality to use a record rather than a percent done to generate the ui component

```
Ext.define('Custom.PercentDone', {
    requires: ['Rally.ui.renderer.template.progressbar.PortfolioItemPercentDoneTemplate', 'Rally.util.HealthColorCalculator'],
    extend  : 'Rally.ui.PercentDone',
    alias   : 'widget.cpercentdone',


    config: {
        record: null
    },

    constructor: function(config) {
        this.initConfig(config);
        config = this.config;
        this.renderTpl = Ext.create('Custom.renderer.template.progressbar.PercentDoneTemplate', {
            calculateColorFn: Ext.bind(function(recordData) {
                console.log('called my custom coloring fn');
                var colorObject = Rally.util.HealthColorCalculator.calculateHealthColorForPortfolioItemData(config.record, config.percentDoneName);
                return colorObject.hex;
            }, this)
        });
        this.renderData = config;
        this.mergeConfig(config);
        this.callParent([this.config]);
    }
});

App.down('#subContainer').add({
    xtype: 'cpercentdone',
    record: item,
    useStoryCount: !App.estimate
});
```

I cannot quite get it to work properly - I want to pass the information to the [calculateHealthColorForPortfolioItemData](https://prod.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/source/HealthColorCalculator.html#Rally-util-HealthColorCalculator) function, but I cannot quite figure out what parameters are being passed and where, so I am not sure what to set and where.

I have also tried using Ext.override:

```
            var percentDone = Ext.create('Rally.ui.PercentDone', {
                record: item,
                percentDoneName: 'PercentDoneByStoryCount'
            });
            var tpl = percentDone.renderTpl;
            tpl.calculateColorFn = function(recordData) {
                var colorObject = Rally.util.HealthColorCalculator.calculateHealthColorForPortfolioItemData(percentDone.record, percentDone.percentDoneName);
                return colorObject.hex;
            };

            Ext.override(percentDone, {
                renderTpl: tpl
            });
            App.down('#subContainer').add(percentDone);
```

Comment: The code in the SDK should be the same as the code in production. (They share the same code) Is there a circumstance where one colors differently than the other?
That being said you can make the component color the bar however you like.

Comment: The percent done UI component only uses a percentage to determine the color, whereas the component used in many of the rally apps uses other data (like start and end dates) to determine if it is in progress, complete, how far from completion, etc.  How can you make the component color the bar as you wish?  I have not been able to find a way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The percent done component determines what color it will be in the same way as we do for Rally in production (since the SDK and prod share the same code). If you look at the template that the component uses [(found here)](https://prod.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/source/PortfolioItemPercentDoneTemplate.html#Rally-ui-renderer-template-progressbar-PortfolioItemPercentDoneTemplate)  you can see that it uses the HealthColorCalculator.

If you want to change the way that the component colors the tooltip you can use [Ext Override](https://prod.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Ext-method-override) and change the functionality of that class to calculate the color however you like

Comment: Got it.  And don't get it.  How can it be calculating the color the same way, using the same algorithm, when it only takes in a percentDone number and no information on the record (yet the coloring algorithm relies on a number of different pieces of information, one of which is a percentComplete)?  Looking at the algorithm again, it doesn't appear to have a special case for when only a percentComplete is provided (in fact it requires a config object).  Sorry, I know you know all of this, I just cannot understand how they are the same when no record is associated with the percent done ui cmp.

Comment: Have you checked into this line where the template calls [calculateHealthColorForPortfolioItemData](https://prod.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/source/HealthColorCalculator.html#Rally-util-HealthColorCalculator-method-calculateHealthColorForPortfolioItemData)?

If you look it has the entire record in the template. That template passes the record to calculate which grabs the fields. (or at least that is how I read it)
No worries about asking for help. It can be a challenge to understand exactly what you are trying to figure out so sometimes it takes a few attempts.

Comment: Ah yes I did see that function, but I forgot that it set defaults for the dates as today if they were not provided.  I see it now.  Thanks!

Comment: I am struggling to override that existing functionality - I feel like all I need to do is provide the correct information, and then it will not use Today if the start/end dates do exist (as far as I understand from the caculateHealthColorForPIData function) - could you take a look at what I have so far?  Edited the question.

Comment: Can I get a code example for this? either showing the Override or being able to set the health color calculator config?